# Local notification custom sound from URL iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, usernotifications

I have successfully recorded and played the voice for the local notification sound and it also get played on calling that function.

But problem is when i give sound's link to the notification sound property, it do not work.

```
notification.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: "martian-gun copy.m4a")
```

Above code works perfectly. But when i gave it URL(in the form of string) it do not play the exact sound.
Code not working is follows:

```
        let fm = FileManager.default
        let docsurl = try! fm.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let myurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("sound.m4a")

        notification.sound = UNNotificationSound.init(named: myurl)
```

myurl have same path at which voice play on playButton.
Finally question is how to set notification custom sound from the sound URL?

Answer (score 1):

According to the document of `UNNotificationSound`, you need to place a copy of your audio file in the `Library/Sounds` folder of your app’s container directory.

```
let docsurl = try FileManager.default.url(for:.documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
let myurl = docsurl.appendingPathComponent("sound.m4a")


let filename = myurl.lastPathComponent

let targetURL = try FileManager.default.soundsLibraryURL(for: filename)

// copy audio file to /Library/Sounds
if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: targetURL.path) {
    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: sourceURL, to: targetURL)
}

let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.sound = UNNotificationSound(named: UNNotificationSoundName(filename))


extension FileManager {

    func soundsLibraryURL(for filename: String) throws -> URL {
        let libraryURL = try url(for: .libraryDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true)
        let soundFolderURL = libraryURL.appendingPathComponent("Sounds", isDirectory: true)
        if !fileExists(atPath: soundFolderURL.path) {
            try createDirectory(at: soundFolderURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true)
        }
        return soundFolderURL.appendingPathComponent(filename, isDirectory: false)
    }
}
```